# Why is the gfortran C preprocessor concatenation token not working?

Tags: fortran, c-preprocessor, gfortran

I'm trying to add a suffix to the name of my subroutines, but I can't get the concatenation token of the C preprocessor to work properly. I have the following example:

test.f90:

```
#define ADD_SUFFIX(name) name##_r

subroutine ADD_SUFFIX(mysub)()
   print*,'Success'
end subroutine

program test
   implicit none
   call mysub_r()
end program
```

Then I run `gfortran -cpp test.f90 -o test.x` and get:

```
test.f90:3.16:
subroutine mysub##_r
           1
Error: Syntax error in SUBROUTINE statement at (1)
```

I'm not very experienced in using preprocessor directives and everywhere I looked I see people using the operator like that (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423620/any-way-to-replace-part-of-word-with-the-preprocessor) for example). Why does it copy the "##" literally in my case and how can I fix it to add suffixes?

Comment: I didn't tag it as fortran because I thought the preprocessor directives should be independent on which language it is applied (not so the compiler used, hence the tag gfortran). However, you and @francescalus are right, the answer was in that other question, apologies for not finding it before.

Comment: It is independent of the language if you call `cpp` directly. But if you call it through `gfortran` it behaves differently from being called from `gcc`.